# Getting an image if it exists with variable file name

Tags: php, html, image

Pretty much explains itself. If I just just get the image to load with this:

```
<img src="/dm cricket/admin/img/tables/<?php htmlout($name);?>_2.jpg">
```

it works, but if I decide to change the code to this:

```
<?php if(file_exists('/dm cricket/admin/img/tables/'.$name.'_2.jpg')){
    ?>
<img src="/dm cricket/admin/img/tables/<?php htmlout($name);?>_2.jpg"><?php }
else {
    echo 'No competition held';}?>
```

it doesn't work, it only echoes 'No competition held'. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: You should avoid using spaces in URLs.

Comment: I know, but it that relevant to the question?

Comment: A hint for you: Your document root is problably not your filesystem root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A root relative URI from the URI of the page as fetched over HTTP is not going to be the same thing as a file path on the file system of the web server.

Assuming a simple configuration of the server, you would have to prefix the file path with the path to the server's web root directory.

Comment: Ah ok, I get it. Added the following to the front of the directory and it worked $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .